# Conversion from ASCII uint8_t to string

Tags: string, serial-data

I am sending a string from a Raspberry Pi to an ESP32 via BT. I am getting one ASCII value per line. How to convert it into one whole String? I tried as follows, but I get an error while running the method  `printReceivedMEssage(buffer)`:

invalid conversion from 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' to 'uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}' [-fpermissive]

```
uint8_t buffer; 

void printReceivedMessage(const uint8_t* buf) {
  char string_var[100];
  size_t bufflen = sizeof(buf);

  for (int i = 0; i < bufflen; ++i) {
    Serial.println(static_cast<char>(buf[i]));
  }

  memcpy( string_var, buf, bufflen );
  string_var[bufflen] = '\0'; // 'str' is now a string
  Serial.print("string_var=");
  Serial.println(string_var);
}

void loop() {
  buffer = (char)SerialBT.read();  
  Serial.println(buffer); // THIS SHOWS AN ASCII VALUES ONE PER LINE
  printReceivedMessage(buffer); // ERROR
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: https://majenko.co.uk/blog/our-blog-1/reading-serial-on-the-arduino-27

Comment: Your buffer is only one byte

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems with your code. They suggest, that you don't know what strings really are.

In C/C++ strings are actually arrays of characters (`char`). A `uint8_t` is the same size of a single character, so you can only save a single character in it. For saving a string, you would need an array of them. So `buffer` should be declared like

```
uint8_t buffer[20] = "";
```

Now `buffer` can hold a string of 19 characters. The 20th character is the terminating null character `\0`, which marks the end of a string. You must always leave enough space for the null character to terminate your strings correctly.

**Serial reading:** There are many ways how you can read from Serial. Look at the `Serial.readStringUntil()` function, which will read from Serial until it reaches a specified character. This way you can easily divide the continuous stream of bytes from Serial into distinct messages. It is common to end all ASCII encoded messages with a newline `\n` character to mark the end of the message. With `Serial.readStringUntil('\n')` (note the single quotes for a single character) you will read until it reaches the newline character (or it times out). You can then process the read string as a full message.

**Providing a string as parameter to a function:** In C/C++ you cannot just provide an array as parameter to a function as other variables. It is a bit more complex. That is because internal the array consists just of a few bytes in a row and the variable just points to the first element of it. It is a pointer (thats a specific C/C++ term). Pointers are marked with `*`, which you already did with your

```
void printReceivedMessage(const uint8_t* buf)
```

function. So the parameter is just a pointer to a `uint8_t`. That also explains the error message, because you provided an `uint8_t`, but the function expects a pointer to `uint8_t` instead. While you still can access the array data through this parameter (given you have implemented what I wrote above about the array), `sizeof(buf)` will only give you the size of the pointer (2 bytes on most Arduino platforms). So you need to add a parameter and also provide the size of the array. Or you can utilize the correct termination of strings with the null character and get the length of the string with `strlen()`. That functions iterates the pointer of the array, until it finds the null character and gives you the resulting length.